# Why is this list comprehension not working?

Tags: python-3.x

In response to a comment, i have put up more details -
Here is the original problem and input format
Given the names and grades for each student in a Physics class of  students, store them in a nested list and print the name(s) of any student(s) having the second lowest grade.

Note: If there are multiple students with the same grade, order their names alphabetically and print each name on a new line.

Input Format

The first line contains an integer, , the number of students. 
The  subsequent lines describe each student over  lines; the first line contains a student's name, and the second line contains their grade.-

Sample input -

```
5
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39
```

Sample Output

```
0

Berry, Harry
```

Here is the coding solution i have so far:

```
marksheet = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    marksheet.append([name, score])
print (marksheet)  
list_score = sorted([name_scores[1]] for name_scores in marksheet)
print (list_score)
list_names = sorted([name_scores[0]] for name_scores in marksheet if 
name_scores[1] == list_score[1])
print (list_names)
```

Everything works until the interpreter reaches the list_names line.
The expected output is `'Harry' and 'Berry'`
However, the program returns only an empty string.

Regards,
Justin

Comment: You may want to provide input data so that  we can run the data against code to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code with sample input provided by you and found that there is a mistake you are doing in line:

```
list_names = sorted([name_scores[0]] for name_scores in marksheet if name_scores[1] == list_score[1])
```

list_score[1] would return a list with value 37.21 in it and you are comparing it with int 37.21 i.e 37.21 = [37.21] which would return false. that's why there is no result.
Try the below code and it will work:

```
marksheet = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    marksheet.append([name, score])
print (marksheet)
list_score = sorted([name_scores[1]] for name_scores in marksheet)
print (list_score)
list_names = sorted([name_scores[0]] for name_scores in marksheet if 
name_scores[1] == list_score[1][0])
print (list_names)
```

Input:

```
5
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39
```

Output:

```
[['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41.0], ['Harsh', 39.0]]
[[37.2], [37.21], [37.21], [39.0], [41.0]]
[['Berry'], ['Harry']]
```